# Lanuage translator in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a sample language translator application,main feature would be::
  If user choose his/her preferred language then all the content of application should be in that language only.

can anybody help me??

Comment: Check my answer in [THIS][1] topic. Maybe help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806061/android-localization/8806240#8806240

Answer (score 1):

Android has built-in support for internationalization of an application. When the user starts an application it looks if the phone's language is available in the application resources.

If you want to add French as a language to your application, you just put the resources in:

```
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

Your default values map will probably be English. What will hapen now is that when the user starts the app, it will show the English strings and other resources if the phone's language is English or any other language but French. If the user's phone is in French, the resources from values-fr will be used.

A guide from Google can be found over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html), another tutorial [here](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/).

Comment: You just need two different strings.xml files. One in values which will be your default and another one in values-languagecode, for example values-fr. just try it with a few example strings, you'll see if it works within a few minuts.